# If $(y_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent, so is $(f(x,y_n(x)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ ?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[a,b] \times [c,d]. $  Consider $(y_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that it is uniformly convergent on   $[e,f] \subseteq [a,b].$ Could anyone advise me on how to prove/disprove that $(f(x,y_n(x)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence on $[e,f]$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you write the definition of 'uniformly convergent' in each of these contexts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that $(f(x,y_n(x)))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge uniformly. For example $(y_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ define by
$$y_n(x)=x^n$$ converge uniformly on $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]$ but if you consider $f$ define by $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$$
for all $(x,y)\in [\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\times \mathbb R_+^* $, this function is continuous but $(f(x,y_n(x)))_{n\in\mathbb N }$ do not converge uniformly. (Actually, it do not converge at all)